# GCC: PLT call missing for non-library

Tags: c, gcc

Lets say I have a `code.c` with two ordinary functions `outer` and `inner`.
`outer` calls `inner`.
I use GCC 11.2 on Linux, x86-64.

If I compile a **shared lib** with
`gcc -shared -fPIC -O3 code.c`
and look at the disassembly of
`objdump -d a.out`
I can see that the ´inner´ call withoin `outer` uses the PLT and is not inlined.
Thats fine and how it should be now even inner-library calls can eg. replaced by LD_PRELOAD.

If I add a main function and compile an **executable** instead
`gcc -fPIE -O3 code.c`
the call is inlined (if small enough etc.) an doesn`t use the PlT.
Fine too.

My problem is this call, a non-library **executable with fPIC**
`gcc -fPIC -O3 code.c`
Now the `inner´ call does not use the PLT (but is not inline either).   The unlinked asm (gcc call with -S) still uses the PLT, just the full binary and its disassembly not anymore.   Adding an explicit` -fsemantic-interposition` does not help.

**Questions**

How can I have PLT calls in my program that is not a library so that things like LD_PRELOAD work even for the functions there?
And whats the point of the non-shared fPIC behaviour to prevent inlining without using the PLT?

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood some thing about ld.so before. Functions in the main executable (ie. the startable program, not shared libraries) are never replacable, therefore using the PlT is useless.

**How ld.so searches for functions**

For PLT function calls, it always uses this search order and takes the first function it finds:

- If a function with that name is available in main executable, this one wins
- If a LD_PRELOAD shared lib was specified, it is checked next.
- Then all normal shared libs are checked, in the order that was specified during linking.

(In each case, only functions in dynsym with global/weak visibility are considered).

No PRELOAD and no linking with -lsomething before the main code files will change anything about it, the main program always comes first.

This implies that a PLT lookup from the main program, for a function that exists there already, will always find its own function. Therefore no PLT lookup is necessary, and not doing it improves performance.

**Dynsym availability**

Unlike shared libraries, startable programs don't need *all* of their global functions listed in dynsym. There are several reasons why a function might be listed, but usually some are missing too.

As long as this behaviour is kept, a PlT lookup from the main program might not even find its own function, therefore again no PLT is better.

**And what about the missing inline optimizations?**

Turned out to be sort of trivial:

When compiling with `-fPIC`, it is not yet clear if that file will later be linked into a startable program or a shared library. Therefore it goes all the way to make it library-suitable: PLT and no inlining.
If it is then linked into a library, that's fine.
For an executable, the linker then removes the PLT indirection again - but it doesn't care about inlining-or-not.

Meanwhile with `-fPIE`, the compiler already knows that this will not become a library, and can do inlining and calls without PLT (at least some of them, and the linker reconverts the rest).

To have inlining, either pay attention to use `fPIC` only for libraries and `fPiE` only for executables, or turn on LTO (`-flto`) which can fix the "missing" inlining after it was made.